# When our hard water is boiled, it leaves a blue-green residue in our kettle.

Tags: water, precipitation

The inside of our kettle is lined in a blue-green deposit. Our water is very hard, but what minerals could cause the coloration?

Comment: Can you post a photo of your kettle? It appears what you desribe as "blue-green deposit" could be explained in various ways.

Comment: To specify: Are you describing a turqouise crust (rare in kettles) or a rainbow like patina (common in kettles or pots)?

Comment: @tipavi You're absolutely right in that a photo would help clear this up. It's great that there's discussion, though))

Comment: Over the last few days I have observed a similar phenomenon in our kettle. We also have blue limescale in our kettle https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R5AI.jpg. This is in a house in Cologne, Germany built in 2016. It was easy to remove with citric acid but I am also wondering about health implications.

Answer (score 4):

If your building's water pipes are made of copper, that could explain the blue-green coloration. Hopefully the inside of your pipe doesn't look like this, though:

[image: Copper Pipe rusting]

Comment: Unlikely that the kettle is made from copper... ;)

Comment: Unlikely that the kettle is a pipe - you might want to amend your answer.

Comment: The implication would be that the tinge of copper comes from the water coming through the pipes.

Comment: Why couldn't the kettle be made of copper? Why couldn't the minerals come from copper piping? I think that's a perfectly logical hypothesis. Also: https://www.google.de/search?q=copper+kettle&espv=2&biw=1422&bih=1070&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi-iYfhu_jNAhXDuxQKHWzqABQQ_AUIBygC&dpr=0.9

Comment: Old buildings have water pipes made of copper - I'll amend my answer to be clearer about that @ToddMinehardt

Comment: While it is a perfectly logical hypothesis, I've never seen a copper kettle in my life. Have you @Zubo? Copper piping in the water supply could theoretically cause a residue as @ITTsoi describes. However, a very common phenomenon in kettles and pots is a rainbowlike patina, a discoloration of steel with high amounts of blueish colours. Similar to what steel experiences due to welding. I reckon it's a more plausible hypothesis that this what is described in the question. A photo of the original kettle should help to clarify this.

Comment: @tipavi I've seen copper kettles... Regarding your hypothesis, are you referring to the colors produced from thin-film interference from the oxidation of steel? I could see this happening in a steel pot by boiling all of the water off. During the last stages of boiling and after, you could easily over temp the pot. A photo would clear this up pretty quickly

Comment: @Tunk OK, I've never seen a copper kettle. But you're right, very old kettles used to have immersion heaters that might have been made from copper. These days kitchen kettles usually have at least a stainless steel bottom. 
Yes, the thin-film interference from oxidation is exactly what I'm referring to, see my answer from Jul 16 '16 at 15:57. Commonly observed in overheated stainless steel pots or kettles running dry. 
I don't have a photo at hand. Maybe a link works: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/38/41/51/384151930c927f855ec1019ff3a840a4.jpg

Answer (score 3):

This is not caused by any mineral in the water, but an oxidation of the kettle's steel itself. Several monolayers of metal oxide are stacked onto each other, basically forming a [dielectric mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_mirror).

Comment: I think that's a possibility, but certainly not the only one! Wouldn't bet on it

Comment: @Zubo: Looking at your comments above I guess we are talking about different phenomena. A photo might help.

Answer (score 3):

This might be dangerous! StackExchange is not necessarily the place to check this with.

If this is CuSO$_4$, that's actually [mildly toxic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate). It could also be something like the German "Grünspan", a copper rust that makes a patina on copper house roofs that's got a blue-green color. It is a mixture of copper hydroxide, carbonate, acetate, and maybe others. This is all not good if this is your drinking water.

You should get that checked by professionals. However, ammonia solution in excess should produce a deep blue tetraamine complex with copper(II)-ions, you could try that (although if it doesn't work, that's by no means a safety assurance).

Have a look [here](http://kupferspuren.at/uploads/RTEmagicC_90b5174647.jpg.jpg) for an example of Grünspan: 
[image: Grünspan]

Answer (score 0):

Limescale consists mainly of calcium carbonate but can also contain other compounds depending on water composition. These include iron hydroxides which while a white solid gains a greenish tinge in the presence of oxygen. That may explain a green limescale in your kettle.